# Is there an easier way to clip background around text?

Tags: css

If I put a background color on a text element, it automatically stretches to 100%.

Usually I'll use `max-width` to clip it, and occasionally `margin`, but there's got to be a better way (or should be, imo).

**[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuX3H/2/)** to demonstrate what I mean. Is there another way that's easier/more effective in getting the background close to text?

Answer (score 2):

You can add to your H3 `display : inline-block`, it won't stretch its width to all the screen.
and add padding as much as you want

Comment: Yes, it should. but be careful, this can let the next element put next to it and not beneath it! you should consider this.

Answer (score 1):

Add an inline, child element and add the background colour to this...

Therefore your HTML would go from

```
<h3 class="red">some text</h3>
<h3 class="red max">some text</h3>
<h3 class="red margin">some text</h3>
<h3 class="red custom">some text</h3>
```

To

```
<h3 class=""><span class="red">some text</span></h3>
<h3 class="max"><span class="red">some text</span></h3>
<h3 class="margin"><span class="red">some text</span></h3>
<h3 class="custom"><span class="red">some text</span></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because H3 is a block element.  If you don't use a block element (such as a SPAN), the background-color will not be stretched like you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack: http://jsfiddle.net/zuX3H/4/

```
h3 { color:white; margin:.2em auto; }
.red { background:red; display:inline; }
.red:after { content:"\A"; white-space:pre; }
* { text-align:center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

H3 is a block element, which means that it won't get only around its content unless you specify a certain width and height. If you want it to do so, the easiest solution is to either change the H3 for something that is inline (ie: a SPAN) or wrap it into a nested element that is.

```
<span class="red">some text</span>
```

or

```
<h3><span class="red">some</span></h3>
```

Comment: I stay  away from fixed units as much as possible. `max-width` over `width`, `em` over `px`. Responsive development is important!

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood, I though you wanted to deal with a "block" element. In that case you are better with something inline like gvee's answer.